# Get Next roll number from table using Oracle Procedure

Tags: oracle11g

```
create or replace procedure "FINDMAX"
(maxroll OUT NUMBER)
is
begin
select max(rollno) into maxroll from std;
end;​
```

in this code maxroll i took to make procedure and rollno i took it as a database field. This gives me maximum(LAST) roll number from table.
Can anyone suggest me how I can get next roll number(max+1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your immediate problem, you can use `max(col) + 1`

```
create or replace procedure "FINDMAX"
(maxroll OUT NUMBER)
is
begin
  select 1 + max(rollno) into maxroll from std;
end;​
```

But if you are getting this to use while inserting the next record, it's not the right way.

You should use sequences instead.

```
create sequence roll_no_seq start with 1 increment by 1;
```

Then use it while inserting using `roll_no_seq.nextval`

Comment: Appreciate your help. Working.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`SEQUENCE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm).

```
CREATE SEQUENCE rollno_seq
    START WITH     1
    INCREMENT BY   1
    NOCACHE
    NOCYCLE;
```

Then you can use,

```
select rollno_seq.nextval from dual;
```

See also, [Basic Elements of Oracle SQL: CURRVAL and NEXTVAL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/server.816/a76989/ch26.htm#4062)